# How to override operator = to copy smart pointer?

Tags: c++

I want to change the operator override = to copy pointers so that it doesn't point to the same memory space but to allocate new memory space and copy data. Thank you for all the code hints

```
class vector
{
    std::shared_ptr<double[]> content;
    int n;
public:
    vector(std::initializer_list<double>list) : content{ new double[list.size()], [](double* p) {std::cout << "usuwam content" << std::endl; delete[] p; } }, n{ static_cast<int>(list.size()) }
    {
        std::memcpy(&content, &list, sizeof(list));
    }
    vector(const vector& vec): content{new double[vec.n]}, n{vec.n}
    {
        //for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            content = vec.content;
    }

    ~vector() = default;

    void print() const
    {
        for (auto i = 0; i < n; ++i)
            std::cout << content.get()[i] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    vector& operator = (const vector& vec)
    {

        std::shared_ptr<double[]> pvc = vec.content;  // should i use shared pointer?
        //for (int i = 0; i < vec.n; ++i)
            //pvc = vec.content;
        content.reset();
        content.swap(pvc);
        n = vec.n;
        return *this;
    }

    double& operator[](int i) { return content[i]; }
};
```

Comment: Why not use a `std::vector<double>`?  It's practically what they were invented for.

Comment: because my task requires using them, the task is to change class vector from standard pointers to smart pointers

Comment: In both your copy constructor, and your `operator=` they are pointing to the same memory location. You need to allocate the array, then copy data over (via loop or `memcpy`)